# Can't create foreign keys in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

It's a basic topic, but I can't find the solution:
I have a `test1` table and a `test2` table:

```
CREATE TABLE test2 (
    id int NOT NULL,
    col1 int NOT NULL,
    col2 int,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE test1 (
    id int NOT NULL,
    col1 int NOT NULL,
    col2 int,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (col1) REFERENCES test2(id)
);
```

So, I want test1.col1 to be a foreign key to test2.id.

But:

- I can insert values to test1 (test1.col1) when test2 is totally empty.
- If I run `SHOW CREATE TABLE 'test1'`, I see this:

  ```
  CREATE TABLE 'tes1t' (
   'id' int(11) NOT NULL,
   'col1' int(11) NOT NULL,
   'col2' int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY ('id'),
   KEY 'col1' ('col1')
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
  ```

  It shows a simple key (not foreign), without any information about the referenced column.
- In TABLE_CONSTRAINTS table there is no row with FOREIGN KEY constraint type.

Why this doesn't work?

My MySQL version: 5.7.14

Comment: Doesn't "work" because `ENGINE=MyISAM`.  Try  `ALTER TABLE test1 ENGINE=INNODB; ALTER TABLE test2 ENGINE=INNODB;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason the table `test1` engine is set to MyISAM. Although according to the MySQL reference. InnoDB is defined as the default storage engine, which is the default as of MySQL 5.5
The reason you do not have foreign keys is due to MyISAM does not support foreign keys.
Try converting the tables to InnoDB.

You can specify the engine to use while creating the table

`CREATE TABLE test2 (
    id int NOT NULL,
    col1 int NOT NULL,
    col2 int,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) engine=innoDB;`

`CREATE TABLE test1 (
    id int NOT NULL,
    col1 int NOT NULL,
    col2 int,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (col1) REFERENCES test2(id)
) engine=innoDB;`

Or altering existing tables by:

`alter table test2 engine=InnoDB;`

`alter table test1 engine=InnoDB;`

And then adding the missing foreign key